# Getting XY parameters from a circle that is converted from rectangle

Tags: javascript, math

We can get the xy parameter from a rectangle based on the point on the rectangle. How to get the similar xy parameters when that rectangle is converted to a circle with four sides of the rectangle becoming four sectors of the circle.

> For example, in this color picker, x denotes saturation percentage and y denotes value percentage. Based on the picker position, I can calculate the saturation and value percentage in the rectangular color picker. But I don't know how to achieve the same in color picker with a circular design.

Just the design of the palette has been changed to circle. As far as I have noticed, 4 sides of the rectangle has become 4 sectors of the circle. Refer the rectangle that I have drawn inside the rectangle.(Correct me if I am wrong.)

#### **Rectangular Color Picker**

[image: ColorPalette in rectangle]

#### **Circular Color Picker**

[image]

Comment: Use a canvas element and retrieve the x,y co-ordinates on the canvas when clicked or moused over by mouse (onmousemove)

Comment: It depends entirely on the rectangle -> circle transformation that you used to come up with above images. Could you include it into your question?